# Remove echo in voip application

Tags: voip

I'm developing a skype-like application to be used without headset, so only with a microphone and speakers. I need something to remove echo, as my microphone will capture also speaker's output in addition to my voice.

I'm developing my application in C#, but I cannot use any library, as I'm using proprietary DLL to do most of the work (including audio encoding), so I need a separate tool from my application. I'm thinking about a software like [Solicall](http://solicall.com/), it creates a virtual microphone linked to the real one, filtering out echo, so you have a clean audio from the virtual microphone to send to the other peer.

This software must run in Windows 7.

Does any of you have experience with *Solicall* or can suggest some better alternatives in terms of echo cancellation? I'm evaluating free and paid solutions, it doesn't matter.